# Tortoise SVN not working with pageant

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn, pageant

I can't do anywthing with repository on TortoiseSVN client. For auth I am using PPK file generated by puttygen. Repo never asked for password.

After hitting update I received this (it popped out instantly, not trying any connection to repo):

[image]

Things that didn't help:

- Filling path to TortoisePlink.exe in settings
- Using another working PPK file from colleague (mine is working on another PC)
- Multiple reinstalls of client

Answer (score 0):

1. Key have to be generated with puttygen, pageant just stores private keys
2. If URL of repo doesn't contain Putty's session-name (properly configured before), you have to use Pageant and have it running with PPK loaded before connection to repository
3. [SSH HowTo](http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto_logemann.html), starting from "SSH key generation and connection check (client)" part have explained all needed steps